# Cannot send invite via Google AppInvites

Tags: android, google-app-invites

In my app I has already working GCM and I has enabled AppInvites in google console. In my project main module I added generated google-services.json and applied 'com.google.gms.google-services' plugin but still
when I trying to send the invites I get a following error:

```
AppInviteAgent﹕ Caller Package Name not found
android.content.pm.PackageManager$NameNotFoundException
        at android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.getPackageInfo(ApplicationPackageManager.java:114)
        at com.google.android.gms.common.util.e.b(SourceFile:823)
        at com.google.android.gms.common.util.e.d(SourceFile:841)
        at com.google.android.gms.appinvite.c.a.a(SourceFile:651)
        at com.google.android.gms.appinvite.c.a.a(SourceFile:229)
        at com.google.android.gms.appinvite.c.b.a(SourceFile:72)
        at com.google.android.gms.appinvite.h.a(SourceFile:34)
        at com.google.android.gms.common.service.g.run(SourceFile:178)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

What could cause this problem?